# HTML5 Audio playlist, play/pause button

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio, playlist

So here is my current html code below

```
<ul id="playlist" class="track-nav">
    <li><a class="collapsed">I </br> RAIN OF GOLD</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(0); playPause(0);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(0);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="collapsed">II </br> ENTER THROUGH THE SUN</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(1); playPause(1);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(1);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="collapsed">III </br> WHITE DOVES</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(2); playPause(2);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(2);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="collapsed">IV </br> AGAINST THE WALL</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(3); playPause(3);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(3);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="collapsed">V </br> BEACHES</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(4); playPause(4);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(4);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="collapsed">VI </br> LET YOU SLEEP TONIGHT</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(5); playPause(5);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(5);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="collapsed">VII </br> FINAL CALL</a>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="changeVideo(6); playPause(6);"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></li>
            <li onclick="playPause(6);" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PAUSE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Along with the current play/pause and my track array playlist.

```
var songs = new Array();
songs[0] = 'assets/music/rain_of_gold.ogg';
songs[1] = 'assets/music/enter_through_the_sun.ogg';
songs[2] = 'assets/music/white_doves.ogg';
songs[3] = 'assets/music/against_the_wall.ogg';
songs[4] = 'assets/music/beaches.ogg';
songs[5] = 'assets/music/let_you_sleep_tonight.ogg';
songs[6] = 'assets/music/final_call.ogg'

var song = new Number();

function playPause(song){

playBoo = false;

//if its not playing than play
if (playBoo == false){
    playBoo = true;

    audioPlayer.src = songs[song];
    audioPlayer.play();

}else{

    playBoo = false;

    audioPlayer.src = songs[song];
    audioPlayer.pause();
} 

 }
```

What I am trying to do is have a div swap for the play/pause but to have one for each song. I've managed to get it somewhat working, but the problem I am facing is that if I click play on one song it will switch the pause div but then if I went to click on another play button under another song that pause button for the other song doesn't revert to the play one. I am not too sure how to target those specific divs if another one is clicked.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where are the changeVideo and playPause functions?

Comment: Sorry, the changeVideo function is just changing the video in the html5 player corresponding to the song. I didnt think it was necessary to post that function as it didnt have much to do with my problem. Its more so the playPause function I've included above

Comment: Also, where's the JavaScript that swaps the play/pause button (or image)? Without seeing more of the code my first guess is that `playBoo = false;` is in the wrong place but I can't be sure yet.